# Sort order in Multilist with Search Field in Content Editor

Tags: content-editor

Using Sitecore 9, I want to order alphabetically the items in a MultiList with Search field in the content editor

In the template, I have the Source:

```
StartSearchLocation=/sitecore/content/Parks/Imported Data/Attributes/Activities&Filter=_template:{C1CD56E2-A02F-46F2-A97A-3392E092918D}&_path:/sitecore/content/Parks/Imported Data/Attributes/Activities&SortField=__DisplayName
```

I've also tried using a field name for the SortField but that's not sorting either.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you see this? https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/8454

Comment: Yes, I saw that but hoped there was fixed in Sitecore 9 and we didn't a custom data source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be to use a custom implementation in the source field. You can do your own class that implements `IDataSource`. It'll essentially just contain a `Item[] ListQuery(Item item);` implementation that will return a list of selectable items of your choice. Then you just reference that class in the Source field in the format `code:your.namespace.yourclass, your.assembly`

Answer (score -1):

Could you try by adding source with **asc** or **desc** in **[ ]** brackets. it is working for me.

```
StartSearchLocation=/sitecore/content/Parks/Imported Data/Attributes/Activities&Filter=_template:{C1CD56E2-A02F-46F2-A97A-3392E092918D}&_path:/sitecore/content/Parks/Imported Data/Attributes/Activities&SortField=__DisplayName [asc]
```

Replace [asc] according to your requirement.